# Find Last Date Value in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have from B1 and onward(C1,D1,etc), I want to find the last date that is filled in. How can I do this in excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear.

1. If you are looking for a maximum date in your range:
   In any any free and empty cell that you could use for the result type:
   =MAX(B1:X1) or use whatever your dates range is. This will give you the last (maximum) date.
2. If you are looking for the last cell that has a date in it and the next cell after it is empty then you could write a formula in cell B2:
   =IF(F1 = "","0",COLUMN(B1)) and then copy this formula below the dates row.
   Now, if the cell above has a date in it the formula will give you a column number which is larger that 1 (because you are starting in column 2 - "B"). If the cell is empty the formula will result in 0. Now you can find MAX(B2:X2) and this will be the number of the last column in row 1 that is not blank that is the last column with a date.

Hope that one of these 2 answers is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

This formula:

```
=MATCH(TODAY()+10000,B1:K1,1)
```

gives us the position (the column number + 1, because we are starting at column B) of the last date in the row. `TODAY()+10000` just gives us a date distant into the future. Rather than using TODAY() you could use `DATE(2013,1,1)+10000`, or even just a v. large number!

This formula:

```
=INDEX(B1:K1,MATCH(TODAY()+10000,B1:K1,1))
```

extends this idea to return the date from the last cell containing a date.

**Note** If the row also contains large numbers which aren't actually dates, then it is a little more complicated.